# Do I need to keep a strong reference to a WeakReference that is only used to perform finalization?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'd like to use a WeakReference as a more efficient finalize() method, for the purpose of freeing native resources associated with an object as soon as it becomes possible to do so, without using finalization (which has significantly higher costs than using a WeakReference).

Since this is the only purpose of the WeakReference (I will never use the WeakReference to obtain the referenced object), it seems wasteful to take the time and space to maintain a list of my WeakReferences to prevent them from being garbage collected.

But if a normal object is constructed and no strong reference is kept to it, it will simply be freed by the garbage collector, and I can't find anything in the Javadoc that suggests this is different for a WeakReference.

Is it necessary to keep a reference to a WeakReference to prevent it from being garbage collected, or, if it's to be enqueued in a ReferenceQueue, will that keep it alive until it's been collected from the queue?

Comment: _I'd like to use a WeakReference as a more efficient finalize() method_ Wait, how?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This involves having a thread dedicated to cleanup of your pseudo-finalizer WeakReferences, and keeping the native resources not in the pseudo-finalizable class, but instead in the WeakReference object. The pseudo-finalizable class keeps a reference to the WeakReference that holds its native resources. When the pseudo-finalizable class is found to be only weakly referenced, the WeakReference is enqueued into the ReferenceQueue you specify at construction of the WeakReference. Your cleanup thread takes from the ReferenceQueue and prompts your WeakReference to do cleanup.

Comment: It's not cheaper from a development time perspective, but can be from a performance perspective if the global lock used when counting finalizable objects becomes a bottleneck, and may help if the JVM gets particularly lazy about collecting your finalizable objects, resulting in excessive memory retention.

Comment: I still don't get it. Your queue will only contain a reference to the `WeakReference` object. How can you cleanup the original wrapped target?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. If you don't have a strong reference to the weak reference you don't have a weak reference either. Or are you asking between a strong reference and a weak reference the weak reference?

Comment: @EJP No, it feels like such a waste of time to make and hold a strong reference that I'm only using as a flag to prevent garbage collection, so I'm wondering if it is really necessary.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You store the information necessary to clean up your native data, database connections, etc. in your subtype of WeakReference, such that you don't need anything but the WeakReference object itself to do the cleanup. If that data changes during the the lifetime of your "real object", then the "real object" that consumers use becomes a bit of a proxy, storing its native data via another object, which happens to be a WeakReference to itself. When the "real object" becomes unreachable, the WeakReference with the resources to be released is added to the queue you specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to keep a reference to a WeakReference to prevent it from being garbage collected

Have a look at the `java.lang.ref` [package description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html), it dedicates a whole paragraph to answering your question:

> The relationship between a registered reference object and its queue is one-sided. That is, a queue does not keep track of the references that are registered with it. If a registered reference becomes unreachable itself, then it will never be enqueued. It is the responsibility of the program using reference objects to ensure that the objects remain reachable for as long as the program is interested in their referents.